# Issue connecting to a MySQL db using mysqli

Tags: php

Last quick question, but my code doesn't work properly. Instead of adding data to my database, he just jumps to the error line that shows up when the connection isn't possible. Please help me, I'm very close to finishing my project. Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Vanille</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include ("realhtmlinphpfile.php"); 
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost") 
or die ("Fehler");

mysqli_select_db($link, "TestsRocks") 
or die ("Verbindung nicht möglich..."); 

$Test1 = $_POST["Test1"]; 
$Test2 = $_POST["Test2"];
$Text3 = $_POST["Test3"]; 
$Test4 = $_POST["Test4"];

if($Test1 == "" or $Test2 == "" or $Test3 == "" or $Test4 == "") {
echo "FAIL";
} else {

$eintrag = "INSERT INTO TestsRocks
(test1, test2, test3, test4);

VALUES 
('$Test1', '$Test2', '$Test3', '$Test4')";

}

mysql_close($verbindung); 
?>
</body>                              
</html>
```

Comment: `mysqli_connect` also needs the username & password.

Comment: You should find a better title for this question, also what is your output ?

Comment: @Sougata [actually, it doesnt](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) but only if he set the default values in a .ini file.

Comment: Yes. But That is not preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing `mysql and mysqli` in your code

Instead of `mysql_close($verbindung)` use `mysqli` and connection variable

You have to use

```
mysqli_close($link);
```

You `mysqli_connet` parameter like

```
$link= mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

You have to execute your insert query

```
$eintrag = "INSERT INTO TestsRocks
(test1, test2, test3, test4);

VALUES 
('$Test1', '$Test2', '$Test3', '$Test4')";

if (!mysqli_query($link,$eintrag)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
}
```

Use  `mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["Test1"]);` before insert data into database

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your database username, your database password and your database name to mysqli_connect, like this:

```
mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
```

If you have ini values for the second, third and fourth parameter, then it should work too.

> mysqli::__construct ([ string $host = ini_get("mysqli.default_host")
>   [, string $username = ini_get("mysqli.default_user") [, string $passwd
>   = ini_get("mysqli.default_pw") [, string $dbname = "" [, int $port = ini_get("mysqli.default_port") [, string $socket =
>   ini_get("mysqli.default_socket") ]]]]]] )

Taken from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php). Note that `mysqli_connect` is an alias of `mysqli::__construct`

Also, use mysqli_* functions instead of mysql_* functions.

You are not running your insert command and you are not preventing SQL injections.